# How to distinguish if a char not found our found in the last position?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

In a system with word length `2^n`, the valid string positions are numbered from 0 to `2^n-1`. If say string::find() finds the character at the last position, it returns  `2^n-1`. If does not find it all, it returns `2^n-1`,
which is the equivalent of -1. How to distinguish the two cases?

This is what I asked in the second half of the deleted question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919438/why-size-t-is-unsigned?noredirect=1#comment71022993_41919438

Comment: If you have that many characters in a string you might want reconsider your design. :) As for a solution to your question consider using [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead, as it uses iterators.

Comment: Valid string positions are up to `max_size()` which can't be 2^n because you can't write that number down, so -1 is automatically available

Comment: @harold But -1 in two's complement yields a value with all bits set, which is the highest representable value with that width and equal to 2^n **- 1**, isn't it?

Comment: @Downvoter yes, that's the point. `max_size()` might be -1 (though I've seen it as -2 often), but that would mean the maximum position is one less than that, leaving -1 available as "not valid" marker

Comment: @Some programmer dude You know, some time ago mr Bill Gates told that nobody may want to use more than 1M bytes :). Also, you may recall year 2000 crisis.

Comment: I mean, if you want to store several gigs of characters in a string, you're probably doing something wrong. It's a *design smell* as well as a *code smell*, and you might want to reconsider your algorithms. Furthermore this question is a typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you want our help with a solution to a problem that you're not telling us. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your strings are really long, the value for the end of the string should be different from the not found value. If the value returned from the string::find is equal to `std::string::npos`, then the phrase cannot be found inside the string.